# Django/python - dispelling confusion regarding dates and timezone-awareness

Tags: python, django, datetime, pytz

I've been working extensively with dates in python/django. In order to solve various use-cases I've been blindly trying a variety of different approaches until one of them worked, without learning the logic behind how the various functions work.

Now it's crunch time. I'd like to ask a couple of questions regarding the intricacies of dates and timezones in django/python.

**How do I interpret a `datetime` object that already has a timezone?**

To clarify, let's say I do the following:

```
>>> generate_a_datetime()
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Canada/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 18:42:00 STD>)
>>>
```

The console output seems ambiguous to me:

Q1) This `datetime` object says that is `2015-12-02` - What is the `generate_a_datetime` function telling me? Is it saying that *"a man standing in eastern Canada looking at his calendar sees "2015-12-02"*? OR does it mean *"This is "2015-12-02 UTC"... but don't forget to adjust this to the eastern-Canada timezone!"*

**django.utils.timezone.make_aware confuses me.**

For example:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> import pytz
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('Canada/Eastern')
>>> now_unaware = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now_aware_with_django = timezone.make_aware(now_unaware, tz)
>>> now_aware_with_datetime = now_unaware.replace(tzinfo=tz)
>>> now_unaware
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 2, 22, 1, 19, 564003)
>>> now_aware_with_django
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 2, 22, 1, 19, 564003, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Canada/Eastern' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)
>>> now_aware_with_datetime
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 2, 22, 1, 19, 564003, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Canada/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 18:42:00 STD>)
>>>
```

The objects `now_aware_with_django` and `now_aware_with_datetime` seem to behave similarly, but their console output suggests they are different.

Q2) What is the difference between `now_aware_with_django` and `now_aware_with_datetime`?

Q3) How do I know if I need to use `timezone.make_aware` or `datetime.replace`?

**Naive datetimes vs. UTC datetimes**

`UTC` means there is no change to the time value. "Naive" seems to mean that the time has no timezone associated with it.

Q4) What is the difference between naive and UTC datetimes? It seems like they are exactly the same - neither imposing any transformation upon the actual time value.

Q5) How do I know when I want to use naive times, and when I want to use UTC times?

If I could get an answer to all 5 questions that would be positively splendid. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1) This datetime object says that is 2015-12-02 - What is the generate_a_datetime function telling me? Is it saying that "a man standing in eastern Canada looking at his calendar sees "2015-12-02"? OR does it mean "This is "2015-12-02 UTC"... but don't forget to adjust this to the eastern-Canada timezone!"**

The first interpretation was correct.  The timezone-aware datetime is already "adjusted" for you, and the tzinfo just telling you which timezone it is specified in.

**Q2) What is the difference between `now_aware_with_django` and `now_aware_with_datetime`?**

For the first case you are creating a datetime which represents the same point in time as the 'naive' one, and that's *assuming* the naive one was in your local timezone.

For the second case, you're saying that the naive one was already in the timezone you're providing, and then you just tack on the tzinfo.

**Q3) How do I know if I need to use `timezone.make_aware` or `datetime.replace?`**

Well, since they do different things, you need to know what you're trying to do to know which to use.  If you want to convert from a naive timezone (in your local time) into a different timezone, you can use `make_aware` for that.  If you *already know* the timezone of your naive datetime, you just use the replace (or look at `localize` in `pytz`, which is a bit more careful about this task).

*Note:* usually if you have any naive datetimes hanging around in the first place, you are doing something wrong earlier on and you should catch that earlier on.  Try to get them tz aware at the boundary of your app - I'll say more about this in Q5.

**Q4) What is the difference between naive and UTC datetimes? It seems like they are exactly the same - neither imposing any transformation upon the actual time value.**

A naive datetime is just a datetime which doesn't tell you what timezone it's in.  It's not necessarily UTC, it could be anything.  It's similar to bytestrings and unicode - you have to know what the encoding is to say what the decoded bytes are saying.  For a naive datetime, you have to know what timezone it's in before you can say what time it actually represents.  So in this sense, a UTC datetime provides more information than a naive datetime.

UTC is coordinated universal time, blame the French for the weird acronym.  Time zones are usually defined as differing from UTC by an integer number of hours, and for all practical purposes you can think of UTC as the timezone which differs from UTC by 0 hours.  And it's like GMT without any daylight savings nonsense.

**Q5) How do I know when I want to use naive times, and when I want to use UTC times?**

There are differences of opinion on this.  My recommendation is to always work with everything in UTC inside your app (and only store UTC in the databases too!).  When any datetime data enters your app, however it enters your app, make sure it's correctly converted to UTC.  This also means that anywhere *inside* your app that uses `datetime.now()` (which is a naive datetime with the "missing" tzinfo which should be the local timezone of the machine) instead uses `datetime.utcnow()` (which is a naive datetime in UTC) or even better `datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)` (which is timezone aware).

Only change into local timezone at the "display" end of your app.  You can usually do this with template tags, or even with clientside js.

Comment: Perfect. +1 for the practical recommendations!